# How to sort a list of objects based on multiple attributes (and also count them) in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, count

This is how my class looks:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, is_old, is_init):
        self.name = name
        self.is_old = is_old
        self.is_init = is_init
```

I have a list of these objects and I want to sort them like this: if the is_init parameter is true, they have to be in the front of the list, if the is_old parameter is true they have to be at the end of the list. The others should be in the middle. I would also like to generate some sort of count for each object (how many have the is_old parameter true, how many have is_init parameter true, etc).

I have been using this:

```
is_init_count = sum(p.is_init == True for p in item_list)
is_old_count = sum(p.is_old == True for p in item_list)
other_count = len(item_list) - is_init_count + is_old_count
```

but I'm thinking there might be a more pythonic way and that this could be done together with the sorting.

Comment: If both `is_old` and `is_init` are `True` for some instances, your `other_count` may run into the negative side, and you have yet to define the sorting behavior for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort with a key that returns a tuple of the properties you're interested in:

```
item_list = sorted(item_list, key=lambda x: (not x.is_init, x.is_new))
```

Note that the `is_old` parameter is saved as `self.is_new` in your class, which may lead to some confusion.

Next, you can loop through this list a single time and count all the properties you're interested in:

```
init = 0
old = 0
for i in item_list:
    if i.is_init:
        init += 1
    if i.is_new:
        old += 1
```